# Deleting char array returned by getenv()

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, getenv

Should I free the memory allocated for the char array, pointer to which is returned by the `char * getenv( char * )` function? And which way - C `free()` or C+ `delete []`? If no - why?

I mean:

```
char * ptr = getenv( "LS_COLORS" );
cout << ptr << endl;
delete [] ptr; //Is this or free() call needed?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original data is stored in the `environ` variable (which is an array of char* and contains all environment variables with their values), `getenv()` only search for the corresponding variable name and returns the position of its value from the `environ` variable, so you don't have to free it, otherwise undefined behavior may be occurred.

Answer (score 4):

Getenv returns a pointer to your processes environment.  It does not need to be deallocated, and it is probably a good idea not to. (delete and free are probably smart enough to do nothing, but corrupting your environment is not a good idea.)

Comment: I wouldn't put any faith in delete or free being "smart enough to do nothing".